# Is it possible to force softkeyboard to show without edittext?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

It works fine if I have EditText visible, but once I set its visibilty to GONE or INVISIBLE, the keyboard doesnt show up anymore, eventhough I have edittext declared in main.xml. So is it even possible to show keyboard w/o edittext?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the Softkeyboard to without edittext as:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.showSoftInput(myView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't seem to work for me...It still only shows the keyboard when there is an EditText with focus. Are there any restrictions on views that can be supplied to showSoftInput?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
InputMethodManager inputMngr = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMngr.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(windowToken, flags)
```

You can get window token on any View by calling **view.getWindowToken()**. Flags can be found in INputMethodManager.

Warning: you must close the keyboard yourself when you're done taking input by calling **inputMngr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, flags)**.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are working in landscape mode, the soft input will create its own text input field ruining all your hard work. You can prevent this behavior:

```
// This makes us remain invisible when in landscape mode.
setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```

Now if you have set up an invisible EditText it will remain as you made it.